# markAsUntouched not clear the red line

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using reactive form with Angular Material.
When I click onsubmit() I want that all params that don't have a value will not show with error(red line)

I try to use `this.formGroup.markAsUntouched();` but it didn't work.

When I don't use on Angular Material, it works.
Does someone know how to do it right with Angular Material?

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formGroup.value)" class="form">
    <mat-form-field class="form-element">
        <input matInput placeholder="Emailaddress" formControlName="email">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>



onSubmit(post) {
    this.formGroup.markAsUntouched();
}
```

The formGroup will be untouched but the red lines still appears.

Answer (score 4):

```
formReset(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    formGroup.control.reset();
    formGroup.control.markAsPristine();
    formGroup.control.markAsUntouched();
}

// for safety measure try calling this function in a try-catch block, it works on a reactive forms
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a red underline, you can reset all FormGroup errors
`this.formGroup.setErrors(null);`

Comment: thanks for your answer. it's work but the problem with this solution is that the required is also remove . the default behavior is   when you enter to the field and out (without writing nothing) the red line will  show and after setErrors(null) it will not show the red line.

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach to suppress all error message

```
Object.keys(this.mygroup.controls).map((field) => {
      const control = this.mygroup.get(field);
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        control.setErrors(null);
      }  
    });
```

Or to individually suppress any message

```
this.mygroup.controls.frmCtrlMyControl.setErrors(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in a form with a single formControl

```
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    Email:                   ['', Validators.required],
  })
```

and I tried all suggestions

```
this.form.controls.Email.setValue('');
this.form.controls.Email.setErrors(null);
this.form.controls.Email.reset();
this.form.controls.Email.markAsUntouched();
this.form.controls.Email.markAsPristine();
```

I also tried resetting the form

```
this.form.reset();
this.form.setErrors(null);
```

but I still have the red line under the email field when I set its value to ''.
[image]

SOLVED by myself.... The error was that I first setErrors to null and THEN I reset the Email field.....instead the order must be

```
this.form.controls.Email.reset();
this.form.controls.Email.setErrors(null);
```